# Overcoming cogging/ripple torque in gimbal motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, compensation

So I'm trying to figure out how to spin a camera on a brushless gimbal motor. I am feeding each of the terminals a sinusoidal pwm signal from a via 3 half bridges on the SN754410. Each of the pwm signals is 120 degrees apart in phase.

When this signal is fed into the motor I get a kind of cogging (almost like a clock) and not smooth motion. see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDNnhxuPoEQ

I am wondering how normal gimbal drivers (for quadcopters and stuff) accomplish smooth motion. From what I understand, you can create acceleration maps with a magnetic position sensor and then do compensation (inverse and apply) to get smooth motion 
[image]
 but it seems like those gimbal motor drivers don't use magnetic postion sensors.

How do those gimbal drivers work?

Comment: Am am also interested if any insight into the method used in the youtube video can be given. I'm not sure exactly how he accomplishes compensation. Apparently he uses a DDS (direct digital synthesizer)

Comment: Torque is proportional to current.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLeS3XZbM8A&list=PLGAApvX09JYpDTTxzb9WJnsZ6pIKEoGI9&index=4  You need to define your design and test results in the context of what does electrical part does not meet capability

Comment: Cogging can be a sign that the PID loop is too aggressive in correcting known position to desired position. Either the derivative is too much (for rapid short-term changes), or the integral is too soft, allowing overshoots in both directions. There are mechanical shock absorbers, but the PID needs to be finely tuned for a given motor and mass.

Comment: Cogging is also a characteristic of PMSM with BLDC exhibiting the highest amount of cogging.

Comment: thanks. Any other feedback/suggestions would be appreciated. I'm having a difficult time getting my motors to operate adequately. I'm thinking it might be easier to just get a gimbal controller like the STorM32 instead of building the motor driver from scratch.

Comment: @DanielCaoili Take a look at the current that goes into the BLDC, it should be almost perfectly sinusoidal when the BLDC is continuously rotating. Maybe your SPWM has a modulator frequency (i.e. the triangular wave) so low that it's not filtered by the RL low pass filter (i.e. each BLDC phase), thus leading to torque ripple.

Comment: What Tony said, but also there's also cogging torque from the magnets attracting the stator, if you can predict that torque you compensate for it and get smooth motion.